# Failure in Cassandra service

Tags: java, cassandra

I have installed cassandra following this link 
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-centos-7/.
But when I start the cassandra service after installation, it shows this error:

```
Job for cassandra.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status cassandra.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status cassandra has the following output:

```
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2020-02-06 13:39:26 EST; 3min 40s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4940 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 06 13:39:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured data...
Feb 06 13:39:25 localhost.localdomain su[4952]: (to cassandra) root on none
Feb 06 13:39:25 localhost.localdomain su[4952]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user cassandra by (uid=0)
Feb 06 13:39:26 localhost.localdomain su[4952]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user cassandra
Feb 06 13:39:26 localhost.localdomain cassandra[4940]: Starting Cassandra: OK
Feb 06 13:39:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cassandra.service: New main PID 5028 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Feb 06 13:39:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cassandra.service: New main PID 5028 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Feb 06 13:39:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Feb 06 13:39:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: distributed storage system for structured data.
```

cassandra system.log file output is:

```
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,012 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,569 Config.java:516 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@1d082e88; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=true; enable_sasi_indexes=true; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/hints; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_negotiable_protocol_version=-2147483648; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; repair_session_max_tree_depth=18; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@60704c; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,570 DatabaseDescriptor.java:381 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,570 DatabaseDescriptor.java:439 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 253MB
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,570 DatabaseDescriptor.java:443 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 253MB
WARN  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,603 DatabaseDescriptor.java:503 - Small commitlog volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 1583.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,604 DatabaseDescriptor.java:530 - Small cdc volume detected at /cdc_raw; setting cdc_total_space_in_mb to 791.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,859 DatabaseDescriptor.java:579 - Only 346.328MiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,905 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:33,906 DatabaseDescriptor.java:773 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
ERROR [main] 2020-02-06 14:33:34,116 CassandraDaemon.java:759 - Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:42) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:330) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:249) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:75) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:143) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:188) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:620) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:742) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
```

After changing port 7199 then starting the service is giving :

```
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 16:23:07,411 StorageService.java:1521 - JOINING: Finish joining ring
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 16:23:07,585 StorageService.java:2442 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 16:23:08,080 NativeTransportService.java:68 - Netty using native Epoll event loop
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 16:23:08,171 Server.java:158 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork26.142ecbb, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.44.Final.452812a]
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 16:23:08,172 Server.java:159 - Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2020-02-06 16:23:08,296 CassandraDaemon.java:556 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-02-06 16:27:35,849 HintsService.java:209 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-02-06 16:27:35,860 Server.java:179 - Stop listening for CQL clients
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-02-06 16:27:35,862 Gossiper.java:1647 - Announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-02-06 16:27:35,904 StorageService.java:2442 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-02-06 16:27:37,908 MessagingService.java:985 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-localhost/127.0.0.1] 2020-02-06 16:27:37,916 MessagingService.java:1346 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2020-02-06 16:27:38,521 HintsService.java:209 - Paused hints dispatch
```

I am not able to figure out the problem as why the service of cassandra is not starting.

Comment: could you provide more information regarding the error? you can find it in the `system.log` file. Are the 'cassandra' group and 'cassandra' user created? does the 'cassandra' user is part of the 'cassandra' group?

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas i have updated the system.log file.

Answer (score 2):

CassandraDaemon.java:759 - Port already in use: 7199
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

Port 7199 is already used. With netstat -tulpn you can display a list of all running applications. Cassandra needs to be able to bind this port.

Comment: how can i change this port so that cassandra can use some other port

Comment: it is in the cassandra-env.sh file: 

JMX_PORT="7199"

Comment: i have updated the output.please have a look as the service is still not starting.

Comment: how much disk space and ram does your machine have? ( df -h and top )

Comment: Do you also have a debug log? That may provide more information why it's shutting down after it starts up.

Comment: Now the cassandra is working fine and systemctl status cassandra command is also showing loaded.Thanks for the help.